# In ROS2, when launching a node service with a launch file, when is the passed parameters populated?

Tags: ros2

I'm trying to make sense of when launch file parameters are populated in ROS2. My situation is similar to the following simplified example; I have a launch file that contains a launch function.

```
def generate_launch_description():
    argument = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "argument", description="Sample parameter/argument"
    )

    service_node = Node(
        package="example",
        executable="my_service",
        name="my_service",
    )

    return LaunchDescription([argument, service_node])
```

...which i call via something like `ros2 launch example example.launch.py argument:=test`
And the node code as such:

```
import rclpy
from rcl_interfaces.msg import ParameterDescriptor
from rclpy.node import Node

class Service(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("llm_service")

        self.declare_parameter(
            "argument",
            "",
            ParameterDescriptor(
                description="Example argument"
            ),
        )

        self.srv = self.create_service(LLM, "prompt", self.prompt_callback)

    def get(self) -> str:
        argument = (
            self.get_parameter("argument").get_parameter_value().string_value
        )
        return argument


def main(args=None):
    # initialize the ROS communication
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    # declare the node constructor
    service = Service()
    # pause the program execution, waits for a request to kill the node (ctrl+c)
    rclpy.spin(service)
    # shutdown the ROS communication
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I call the init for my service, the argument is not set, and if I called `get()` it'd return the default value of `""` . If I had a callback trigger later, say through something like a service call, and I called `get()` then, I would get the correct populated value from the launch file.

So when does that get populated? What is the best accepted pattern for grabbing those arguments on service startup such that I can use it for initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above populates parameters correctly when I swapped the launchfile from what is described above to:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    service_node = Node(
        package="example",
        executable="my_service",
        name="my_service",
        parameters=[{"example": "test"}],
    )

    return LaunchDescription([service_node])
```

...specifically, using the `parameters` keyword argument in the service node over a launch file argument; I am unsure at the moment why, or why the tutorial I read [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/How-To-Guides/Launch-file-different-formats.html) suggested `DeclareLaunchArgument`.